# Prefere search results in a special country

Tags: google-custom-search

I want to do a search for products. I also get some results but they are located in the USA with currency USD but I want to get results from Germany with EUR instead. The language of the custom search is already set to German but the prefered search results are from US.

Is there a possibility to prefere german sides only?

Thanks for your answeres!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restrict or boost results from Germany with `cr` or `gl` attribute.

> `cr`  Restricts search results to documents originating in a
>   particular country.
>
> `gl`  Boost search results whose country of origin matches the
>   parameter value.

So, you could try:

```
<gcse:search cr="countryDE"></gcse:search>
```

Or:

```
<gcse:search gl="de"></gcse:search>
```

Custom Search Element Control API / Supported Attributes
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

If you don't need "global" search, and all, or the most of your CSE implementations should be restricted to Germany, then you could set default `cr` or `gl` on https://cse.google.com/ > Search features > Advanced > Websearch restricts. ("Country Restrict" and "Boost Results By Locale".)

[image]